# Dropdown Validation - Still Submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm currently using a dropdown validator that works, but it still submits the form when I receive an error.

In the body tag:

```
<select style="font-face:verdana; font-size:10px; border:thin; width:140px; position:relative; left:94px; top:140px;" id="Round-1-East-Series1" name="Round-1-East-Series1">
<option value="0">-select team-</option>
<option>Detroit Redwings</option>
<option>Boston Bruins</option>
</select><br>
```

And then...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate()
    {
        var e = document.getElementById("Round-1-East-Series1");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        if(strUser==0)
        {
            alert("Please select a team.");
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my submitter:

```
<input style="font-face:verdana; font-size:14px; text-align:center; border:thin;" onclick="Validate()" type="submit" value="Send">
```

What I want to happen is that if the field returns "Please select a team," it doesn't submit; it stays on the page so that my careless user is forced to fill that team out.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your onclick function:

```
onClick="return Validate()";
```

And inside Validate function after :

```
{
    alert('Please select a team ');
    return false;
}
```

So, for valid cases return true and for failed validation return false..
This would surely do your job..

Comment: Sweet, looks like it worked!  You're my favorite for the day.